# Creating a BLOB in an Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, blob

Using VB.Net I am trying to create an Access table with a BLOB field. I have successfully created the table using Access itself and declaring the field as "Ole Object".  However, for customers, I must create the table programmatically.  I have tried:

```
create table BLOBTABLE (BlobFileName TEXT(255)   NOT NULL ,  BlobData LongVarBinary )
```

and get a table create error.  In my ConnectionString I'm using "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0".  I'm guessing it doesn't like the LongVarBinary datatype, but I'm not sure what else to use. Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: [Office 2013 Access Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193793.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Steve,. but that list doesn't say what the corresponding oledb data type is for ms Access "Ole Object".  Everything I researched leads me to believe it's "LongVarBinary", but as I said, that throws an exception so I must be missing something.

Comment: Well with BINARY or LONGBINARY it will work, however without knowing exactly what you want to store there I can only suggest to avoid storing binary data in a database column. Instead store a relative path to the operating system file that contains the data. In this way you can avoid the limitations of MS-Access Jet format (2GB max mdb size).

Comment: HI Steve.  Yep, right now I do store the relative path, but the customer wants to be able to store the referenced documents (could be pdf, or doc files) right in the database.  So those are the kind of "large binary objects" I need to store.  So I guess the question is when you declare a field to be "ole object" in the access application, what oledbtype does it actually translate to, and can, using the jet ver 4.0 engine, create that same type of field in a vb.net application?

Comment: Also, my understanding is that the "blob" field is stored separately (like a memo field) and does not contribute to the 2GB limitation of the mdb file.

Comment: If you create the table field with LONGBINARY it will be showed as an Ole Obiect in MS Access interface without limitations in size for the single object. For the 2GB total mdb limit I am not sure about it, I don't think that you get this distinction in MS-Access. Ready to be proved wrong by some expert in MS-Access tech.

Comment: Also you can find this useful http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Access_Limits

Comment: Found the answer Steve.  LongBinary threw an exception, but, just out of desperation I tried declaring it as "oleobject" and it worked!  double checked the field in the access application and it was, indeed, and "ole object"!  NOWHERE did I find ANY reference that "oleobject" was a valid declaration type... Unbelievable. Hope this post can help some other programmer at some point!

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to programmatically declare a "blob" (ie "ole object" type) for an access database is:
create table BLOBTABLE (BlobFileName TEXT(255)   NOT NULL ,  BlobData oleobject)

Discovered this by trial and error.  Didn't find it documented anywhere.